# ID match with different fields using if condtion in JS?

Tags: javascript

I Have two objects booking and History. I have to check booking userId matches with History userId or History CustomerID

If booking userId matches with any of these two fields(History userId or History CustomerID) we should return "ID matched" in the console.

If booking userId does not match with any of these two fields(History userId or History CustomerID). we should not return anything.

Below is my code .its working as expected but is this a better approach? or i can do this in some other way

Please suggest

```js
var booking = {"userId":"1233","CustomerID":null,"username":"av"};
var History = {"userId":"123","CustomerID":null,"username":"av"};

var a = booking.userId != History.userId;
var b = booking.userId == History.CustomerID;
var c = booking.userId == History.userId;
var d = booking.userId != History.CustomerID;
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
console.log(c)
console.log(d)

if( a && !b || c && !d)
{
console.log("ID not mathced with booking ")
}
```

Comment: `c` and `d` are redundant, because `c` is the same as `!a`, and `d` is the same as `!b`. You can get rid of them and just use `a` and `b`.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi please post your answer

Comment: In the code you pasted here, `c && !d` means when they are both equal, and in that case, you are returning no match. Is that what you want?

Comment: I have updated my code. if its match any of these two fields we should not return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your boolean definitions, you can notice that `c` and `d` are redundant, that's because `c` is the same as `!a`, and `d` is the same as `!b`. You can get rid of them and just use `a` and `b`. I'd also suggest using inequality for both, just for consistancy. In this case, the code becomes:

```js
const booking = { "userId": "1233", "CustomerID": null, "username": "av" };
const History = { "userId": "123", "CustomerID": null, "username": "av" };
const a = booking.userId !== History.userId;
const b = booking.userId !== History.CustomerID;

if (a && b) {
    console.log('ID not matched with booking');
}
```

You can also omit the variables definitions and directly do:

```
if (booking.userId !== History.userId && booking.userId !== History.CustomerID)
```

And if the list of things to compare to gets longer, you can use the following trick to reduce the size of the `if` statement:

```
if (![History.userId, History.CustomerID].includes(booking.userId))
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to check if a variable matches multiple values is as follows:

```
const match = [History.userId, History.CustomerID].includes(booking.userId);
```

It creates an array of the possible values and checks if any of them match the value to be matched.

Comment: if statement should return "ID not matched with booking" because I have to check other fields values are not matched in if statement

Comment: @itsme you can create an if statement with the variable `match` as the condition and then do whatever you like inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this...

```js
var booking = {"userId":"1233","CustomerID":null,"username":"av"};
var History = {"userId":"123","CustomerID":null,"username":"av"};

var match = booking.userId === History.userId || booking.userId === History.CustomerID;
if  (match)
  console.log("ID mathced")
else
  console.log("ID not mathced with booking ")
```

Comment: if statement should return "ID not matched with booking" because I have to check other fields values are not matched in if statement

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The answer is in your problem statement `booking userId matches with History userId or History CustomerID`

```js
var booking = {
  "userId": "1233",
  "CustomerID": null,
  "username": "av"
};
var History = {
  "userId": "123",
  "CustomerID": null,
  "username": "av"
};

if (booking.userId === History.userId || booking.userId === History.CustomerID) {
  console.log('ID matched.');
} else {
  console.log('ID not matched with booking.');
}
```

Comment: if statement should return "ID not matched with booking" because I have to check other fields values are not matched in if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this the best way and the easiest way I think.

```js
var booking = {"userId":"1233","CustomerID":null,"username":"av"};
var History = {"userId":"123","CustomerID":null,"username":"av"};

 booking.userId === History.userId ? console.log("ID Matched") : console.log("ID not matched with booking ");
```